# How to convert digital value from MEMS mic to dB

Tags: signal-analysis, audio-processing

I have built 3x3 microphone array using 24bit ICS-52000 microphones. I want to convert digital values to decibels. I'm getting data via serial port into MATLAB and I used this code to convert those values to dB:

```
%get data from .txt
data = load('pelne obc.txt');

%get data from microphones
time = data(:, 1);
signals = data(:, 2:10);
zeroIndex = signals == 0;
signals(zeroIndex) = 1;

dBvalues = abs(20 * log10((signals) / (2^23 - 1)));
```

This is how the signal looks on charts
[image]

Am I doing I correctly? mean value looks good, but those ~130 dB peaks aren't real. I measured acoustic signal of induction motor from a distance of 1 meter.

Comment: Are you looking for dBSPL, dBFS, dB(A) ? There are quite a few different types of "dB" and it would help to clarify what exactly you need.

Comment: @Hilmar I'm looking for dBSPL

Comment: @erysvh: that's all very well explained in the data sheet of the microphone (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/400/DS-000121-ICS-52000-v1.3-1114907.pdf) specifically page 13. Which part do you have trouble with ?

Comment: I have answered a similar question from same user on EE.SE already. I explained how the dB SPL relates to dB FS output of the mic. So this must be about how to convert PCM samples to dB FS.  But I don't think it is simply by converting each sample into dB that will be useful. Imagine a 0dBFS sine wave, should it show constant 0dBFS or wiggle between 0 and minus infinity?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it wiggle between $0$ and $-\infty$? That’s what it would look like on most DAWs

Comment: @Jdip: DAWs doing either time and/or frequency averaging before displaying a bar.  Converting samples to dB on a sample per sample basis makes little sense. It also seems like OP wants to build a sound pressure level meter, in which case it needs to be calibrated, which isn't all that hard for a PDM mic.

Comment: @Hilmar Daws do not do any time averaging for dB time displays. See for example Adobe Audition. For a level meter, absolutely agree with you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logarithms of negative values are not defined in real values, in the same way that square roots of negative numbers aren't defined in the real numbers.

The proper way would be to take the absolute value first, then convert:

```matlab
dBvalues = 20 * log10( abs( signals / (2^23 - 1) ) );
```

Alternatively, you could take the real part (see note at the end):

```matlab
dBvalues = real( 20 * log10( signals / (2^23 - 1) ) );
```

This will give you dBFS values. To convert to dBSPL, refer to the [specs](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/400/DS-000121-ICS-52000-v1.3-1114907.pdf):

> An acoustic input signal of a 1 kHz sine wave at 94 dB SPL applied to
> the ICS-52000 results in an output signal with a −26 dB FS level

So simply add the calibration offset $94+26 = 120$ to your dBFS values to get dBSPL:

```matlab
dBFS = 20 * log10( abs( signals / (2^23 - 1) ) ) ;
dBSPL = dBFS + 120;
```

If you're going for a sound level meter, you'd probably want to compute the RMS value in successive windows (of your chosen length) before converting to dBFS in the formula above.

---

**Note**

When taking the logarithm of a negative number, the result is complex: to see this, consider a negative number $-x$. Using Euler's formula, this number can be written:
$$-x = x \times e^{i\pi}$$

The logarithm of $-x$ is then $$\log(-x) = \log(x \times e^{i\pi}) = \log(x) \times \log(e^{i\pi}) = \log(x) + i\pi$$
which is a complex number with the real part equal to the logarithm of the absolute value of $-x$ and the imaginary part is $\pi$.

In base 10, we have $\log_{10}(e^{i\pi}) = \frac{\log_e(i\pi)}{\log_e(10)} = \frac{i\pi}{\log_e(10)}$ which yields:
$$\log_{10}(-x) = \log_{10}(x) + i\frac{\pi}{\log_e(10)}$$